# Supply images for slideshow dynamically from HTML (jQuery map/get)

Tags: jquery, image, dictionary, slideshow, jquery-backstretch

I am using awesome plugin [jQuery BackStretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) for my background slideshow. This is the common way how to pass images to it.

```
$.backstretch([
    "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg", 
    "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg", 
    "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

I don't want to supply images for it by hardcoding though, I want the function to grab what my PHP generates inside that container. Here's what I have so far.

```
var images = $('#background img').map(function() { return this.src; }).get();
$.backstretch([$images], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

And that, obviously, doesn't work - according to FireBug, variable images is not defined (?) . although if I "alert" the variable, it shows comma separated urls of images.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: What does the php look like

Comment: so u want to use `backstretch` from a list of `images` right? Assuming that is `#background img` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be suffice. `backstretch` is expecting the first argument to be an array of strings that are references to images.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = [];

    // iterate over your selection
    $('#background img').each(function () {
        // save source to list
        images.push(this.src);
    });

    // use plugin
    $.backstretch(images, {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
});
```

Also I'm assuming your HTML is something like this...

```
<div id="background">
    <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg" />
    <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg" />
</div>
```